# Node.js send static files such as HTML files

Tags: node.js

I'm using the following script to show an html file in my browser:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http"),  
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    fs = require("fs");  

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);
    path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            response.sendHeader(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            response.close();
            return;
        }

        fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                response.sendHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                response.write(err + "\n");
                response.close();
                return;
            }

            response.sendHeader(200);
            response.write(file, "binary");
            response.close();
        });  
    });  
}).listen(8080);  

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

But when I try to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/path/to/file` I receive this error:

```
Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendHeader'
(at line 16).
```

I'm using node-v0.4.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node v0.4.12 there is no method `sendHeader` but it looks like the method `response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])` has the same API, so you could just try to replace your `sendHeader`  by `writeHead`.

See : http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse

Comment: thansk! there is others istruction that i have to re-write (as for example close() widht end()) but now it work

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading this recently, should also note that the response object uses response.end() now and not response.close()